# How to debug exception on other thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have a lot of shortlived threads that updates my program, by events fired from a socket connection. My problem is I don't know how to debug this, like how to get the proper information on where in the code the exceptions occur. Because I get for example an exception like below, and this will just be the print in the Immidiate Window. There is no pop-up window, and it does not highlight any line in the code or show even what method it was in.

What am I missing? What I can do to see these things?  And what improvements does VS2010 give on this situation, if any?

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in Krs.Ats.IBNet.dll
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to "Debug -> Exceptions...", locate the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and check the "Thrown" mark. Now start debugging your application. Once any of CLR exception occurs the execution will stop on that line.

Comment: solved also totally different: until now the debugger was freezing after each run. Once I changed the debugging option as in @volpav answer, the IDE returns immediately after code execution!